# AVAssetWriter audio settings failure with compression settings

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I have the following audio compression settings which fail with AVAssetWriter (`mov` container, `HEVC` codec, `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` format ID):

```
["AVSampleRateKey": 48000,  "AVFormatIDKey": 1633772320, "AVNumberOfChannelsKey": 1, "AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey": 128000, "AVChannelLayoutKey": <02006500 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000>]
```

Want to understand what is wrong? I can not reproduce it at my end (only reproducible on user's device with a particular microphone).

Here is the code line that fails:

```
 if _assetWriter?.canApply(outputSettings: audioSettings!, forMediaType: AVMediaType.audio) ?? false {

 } else {
     /* Failure */
 }
```

I need to know if it is mandatory to provide value for `AVChannelLayoutKey` in the dictionary with `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`? That could be a possible culprit.

Another set of settings that fail with `lpcm` codec for same `hevc` and `mov` is following:

```
   ["AVSampleRateKey": 48000, "AVChannelLayoutKey": <02006500 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000>, "AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey": 0, "AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey": 16, "AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved": 0, "AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey": 0, "AVNumberOfChannelsKey": 0, "AVFormatIDKey": 1819304813]
```

EDIT: I fixed the issue by defining my own `AudioChannelLayout` as opposed to getting it from incoming `CMSampleBuffers` in the audio stream.

```
        var channelLayout = AudioChannelLayout()
        channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_MPEG_2_0
        
        let numChannels = 2 //Stereo Audio
        let currentChannelLayoutData = Data(bytes: &channelLayout, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: channelLayout))
```

The code above seems to convert all kinds of audio streams to stereo. Not sure how mono to stereo (or 4 channel to stereo) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AudioChannelLayout` contains the tag `kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo` (0x02006500 in little endian memory order), which disagrees with the `AVNumberOfChannelsKey` count of 1.

Sounds like your user has a stereo microphone and you're expecting mono.

> The code above seems to convert all kinds of audio streams to stereo. Not sure how mono to stereo (or 4 channel to stereo) works.

IIRC, in general, Apple audio channel conversion discards extra channels. `AVAssetWriter` *might* add zero samples if you don't provide enough channels. Try it and let us know!